# List won't filter in right way

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I just tried to create a List of People and a TextBox for filtering

thats my xaml:

```
        <ListView x:Name="Mitarbeiterauswahl" 
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Mitarbeiterauswahlliste"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MitarbeiterListe}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MitarbeiterListeTemplate}"
        ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True" 
        IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" 
        IsHoldingEnabled="False" 
        IsRightTapEnabled="False"
        ItemClick="MitarbeiterAnrufen"
              />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Margin="19,0,19,0">
        <TextBox PlaceholderText="suchen ..." KeyUp="ListeAktualisieren" InputScope="Search" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" />
    </StackPanel>
```

my code-behind:

```
    private void ListeAktualisieren(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _viewmodel.filter = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    }
```

my viewmodel:

```
    public List<Mitarbeiter> MitarbeiterListe
    {
        get 
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filter) || this._MitarbeiterListe==null)
            {
                return this._MitarbeiterListe;
            }
            else
            {
                return this._MitarbeiterListe.Where(item => item.name_vorname.ToLower().Contains(_filter.ToLower())).ToList();
            }
        }
        set 
        { 
            this._MitarbeiterListe = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(); 
        }
    }
    private List<Mitarbeiter> _MitarbeiterListe;

    public string filter 
    { 
        get { return _filter; } 
        set 
        { 
            _filter = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("MitarbeiterListe"); 
        } 
    }
    private string _filter = "baza";
```

as you can see, at the beginning _filter="baza" and the filter works, the List Returns just one Item, the Person whose Name includes "baza".
BUT if i type in "baza" in the TextBox, the List is empty. moreover: I can type 2 characters, the List will filter correctly, typing the third character the List will be always empty.

does anybody know why this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

omg ... thats really embarrassing ...

the reason why my List was empty: the visibility of the Keyboard moved the sight of the List (which was now really short, e.g. 1 item) out of the visibility of the Screen ...

I'm sorry for that stupid question, my program works as expected ...